# How to test this GEDCOM parser?

Tags: python, parsing, parameter-passing, attributeerror, gedcom

I was trying to test this parser with my gedcom file. I do not understand how to call some of the functions and what parameters are to be given. 
Example, in the families function, I need to pass an individual as the parameter but if I type a Person's full name or even his ID it does not accept. I get an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_individual'".

https://github.com/madprime/python-gedcom

I appreciate the help. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re your specific example: In the `gedcom/__init__.py` file, the `is_individual` method is only defined for the `Element` class, so presumably the `families` method is assuming that (the value bound to) its `individual` parameter is an instance of that class. In your case, this would be one of the many `Element` instances created when the parser parses your gedcom file, which you can get at via the `element_list` or `element_dict` methods of the `Gedcom` class.

Note: In the repo you link to, the README says that the project has moved [elsewhere](https://github.com/nickreynke/python-gedcom). You should probably use the parser there. Moreover, if you raise an issue there, they might expand the documentation to answer your questions.